# python symbolic summation and differentiation of a vector of parametric size

Tags: python, sympy

This question concerns iterating over, and differentiating of, vector variables of parametric size in sympy. They are not given, and never will be.

For instance, take the following simple setup:

I have M vectors x, each of dimension K.
and I have a weights vector w, also of dimension K.
(M and K will never take on a value, they will just stay M and K).

My function sums over the x vectors, and then performs a dot-product of the sum with the weights w:

```
f = dot(sum(x),w)
```

The function's derivative w.r.t w_i should be sum(x_i), i = 1..M

How do I code that in sympy? both the summation, and the differentiation.

---

### EDIT

Since Francesco's great answers made clear that this is currently not possible, I'm looking for a workaround.
In other words: is it possible to:

1. define fixed dimensions (e.g., M=100, K = 200);
2. define my function f in sympy
3. compute f.diff(w_1), f.diff(w_2), etc
4. deduce **automatically** from the output a common form for f.diff(w_i)? (by collecting terms, or something similar)?

I'm already kind of doing step 4 **manually** by breaking the derivative into simpler terms to make it more readable, and then looking for 'patterns'. I'm using this code [taken from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22665990/optimize-code-generated-by-sympy) for readability:

```
tmpsyms = numbered_symbols("tmp")
symbols_list, assignements = cse((grad_0), symbols=tmpsyms)
for (symb, ass) in symbols_list:
    print (str(symb) + ' = ' + str(ass))
print(assignements)
```

Comment: Did you try derive_by_array( ) for your step 4?

Comment: Never heard of it. I'll give it a try. thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the new tensor-array module introduced in SymPy version 1.0.

I suppose that your *K* and *M* parameters are numbers, not symbols (otherwise I'd suggest to use *sympy.tensor.Indexed*).

Consider this example: *X* is array of two vectors, each of length 3. Therefore *X* is a tensor of rank 2 and shape (2, 3).
I also chose a simple example of weight vector with symbols in it:

```
In [1]: from sympy import *
In [2]: from sympy.tensor.array import *

In [3]: var("a,b,c,d,e,f")
Out[3]: (a, b, c, d, e, f)

In [4]: X = Array([[a, b, c], [d, e, f]])

In [5]: var("w1,w2,w3")
Out[5]: (w1, w2, w3)

In [6]: W = Array([w1, w2, w3])
```

Create now a product tensor with three indices (2 from *X*, 1 from *W*):

```
In [7]: tp = tensorproduct(X, W)

In [8]: tp
Out[8]: [[[a*w1, a*w2, a*w3], [b*w1, b*w2, b*w3], [c*w1, c*w2, c*w3]], [[d*w1, d*w2, d*w3], [e*w1, e*w2, e*w3], [f*w1, f*w2, f*w3]]]

In [9]: tp.shape
Out[9]: (2, 3, 3)
```

Let's sum over the 2nd and 3rd indices (index 1 and 2 in Python notation, as indices start from zero), this is equivalent to what you call *dot* product:

```
In [10]: tensorcontraction(tp, (1, 2))
Out[10]: [a*w1 + b*w2 + c*w3, d*w1 + e*w2 + f*w3]
```

The same expression can be summed over:

```
In [12]: stc = sum(tensorcontraction(tp, (1, 2)))

In [13]: stc
Out[13]: a*w1 + b*w2 + c*w3 + d*w1 + e*w2 + f*w3
```

For derivatives of arrays, you could use *derive_by_array(...)*. It will create a tensor of higher rank, with each of its components derived by a component of the latter argument:

```
In [14]: derive_by_array(stc, W)
Out[14]: [a + d, b + e, c + f]
```

**EDIT**

Since it has now been specified that the parameters *M* and *K* are symbolic, I'll add this part.

Declare *X* and *W* as *IndexBase*:

```
In [1]: X = IndexedBase("X")

In [2]: W = IndexedBase("W")

In [3]: var("i,j,M,K", integer=True)
Out[3]: (i, j, M, K)
```

Your expression is the sum of the product *X W* over indices *i* and *j*, expressed as follows:

```
In [4]: s = Sum(X[i, j]*W[j], (i, 1, M), (j, 1, K))

In [5]: s
Out[5]: 
  K     M               
 ___   ___              
 ╲     ╲                
  ╲     ╲   W[j]⋅X[i, j]
  ╱     ╱               
 ╱     ╱                
 ‾‾‾   ‾‾‾              
j = 1 i = 1
```

Now, one would derive `s.diff(W[j])` or with a different index `s.diff(W[k])`, unfortunately this has not yet been implemented in SymPy.
There was a PR on github, which would add support for the derivative of indexed objects, but it hasn't been merged so far:
https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/9314

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer; but, actually, my K and M parameters are **not** numbers; that's my difficulty. I've edited the original question to reflect that.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the two detailed answers. That's really great help; thank you very much. I've updated my question now following your answer. But I wouldn't dare to ask for a third great answer.... :-)